# GLSurfaceView camera preview is scrambled after resize

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, android-mediacodec

I use a GLSurfaceView to render camera preview output whilst simultaneously encoding it with the MediaCodec.

At some point, I want to resize the GLSurfaceView to show a larger camera preview. I do this by pausing the camera preview, applying new layout params to the GLSurfaceView and then restarting the camera preview.

The GLSurfaceView resizes successfully but the preview inside is the same size as before. The rest of the GLSurfaceView is filled with scrambled data (see attached image).

[image]

Comment: Using the Camera2 API? I know it pays attention to the target Surface size, but I don't know if it follows changes.

Comment: No, using the original camera API. I did a little experiment using one of your examples in Grafika. I got the same result but was able to get it to sort itself out by setting the visibility to GONE and then VISIBLE again. However, this simple trick did not work for me in my own app. Possibly because i've got a bit more going on with the camera preview being overlaid on top of a downstream video feed. In any case, new requirements have come in that mean my solution of tearing everything down is kind of needed anyway (switching resolution etc) so there is no wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who find this, I never did manage to resolve my issue.

I had to tear down the whole view, camera and encoder and rebuild everything.